# Translating CSV files in Chinese to English Programmatically

Tags: c++, python, translation, chinese-locale

I have many files which are in chinese and I am trying to figure out a way to programmtically translate them into English files. The files can have as much as 10k lines of chinese text. Anyone have any insightful input on how to accomplish this? Im not really bound to one programming language, although i feel something like python would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing and writing a CSV file using the 'csv' module of Python is trivial, well documented...please do some research. In addition: there are various translation services available that can be used for free or as a paid service (e.g. Google Translate). See
this thread for options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api